# Laravel sail 10, getting 503 Service Unavailable by running sail up -d

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sail, laravel-10

Since today, if I run `sail artisan up -d`, I get `503 Service Unavailable`.

My Docker on my pc is up to date. I have run different commands in the hope that it will solve the problem but it didn't.

##### `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}" ]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        platform: linux/x86_64
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health" ]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
```

##### `hosts` file

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
#127.0.0.1 webserver.local

# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.1.44 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.44 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

I have searched to find a solution but I haven't found it yet. I'm wondering how it is possible that suddenly it doesn't work anymore.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Anything useful in your container logs?

Comment: I have checked that. nothing useful

Comment: You will have to start basic debugging, for example, the `laravel.test` container is the one serving the Laravel, so you could add any `.txt` file in the `public` folder and see if it is accessible. If you still have issues, I would create/find/use a basic `nginx` container using `docker-compose` (disregard Laravel Sail), and see if you can still access anything from it (check that the networking still works), and then you can continue trying to debug networking